# difference between Add New Report & Add New Item in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report

what is the difference between Add New Report & Add New Item in SSRS?when I create report with Report Wizard ,a Report1 - Backup(.rdl) produced that I can load it in Dashboard but when I create report with Add New Item , a report1(.rdl) produced that I can not load it in Dashboard .

Answer (score 0):

Add New Report launches the Report Wizard.

Add New Item allows you to add a Report, Data Source, or Dataset. If you resort to the latter, you may have to add the objects to Report Viewer manually.

Comment: what is your desired end result?

Comment: I want to load rdl file to the Dashboard which I work with it but when I create report with Add New Item it does not load and give this error : Your RDL file has wrong file format. Please use SQL Server (2005 or 2000) Business Intelligence Development Studio to create the RDL file.

Comment: but when I create report with Add New Report (wizard) it gives me 2 reports file that one of them is Report - Backup and I can load and see it in Dashboard and another one is report that I can not load and see it in Dashboard.

Comment: my SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio is 2008(R2)

Answer (score 0):

New Report is also sub point of Add New Item.
In other hands, we can say that Add New Item contains many item as well as Report.